# laravel API fetch data from table base on the unique id

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-8, laravel-api

I want to create an API that display and fetch data from table(**users**) and another table(**fruits**) together base on the unique id (**fruit_id**) common in both table.

```
table->users
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+
|  Id      | Fruit_id   | Name     | Gender       |
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+
|  1       | B456       | Mary     | Female       |
|  2       | O174       | James    | Male         |

table->fruits
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+
|  Id      | Fruit_id   | Name     | Quantity     |
+----------+------------+----------+--------------+
|  1       | B456       | Banana    | 22          |
|  2       | O174       | Orange    | 34          |
```

I created an API in laravel where fetch all data in the users table from my controller

```
class UserApiController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return Users::all();
    }
}
```

**API display result**

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        fruit_id: B456,
        name: Mary,
        gender: Female,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        fruit_id: O174,
        name: James,
        gender: Male,
    }
]
```

I want the API to display like the below based on the unique id (**fruit_id**) selection that is common between both tables how will I write the code in my controller to display the desired result.

**Desired result**

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        fruit_id: B456,
        name: Mary,
        gender: Female,
        fruits: [
            id: 1,
            fruit_id: B456,
            name: Banana,
            Quantity: 22,
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        fruit_id: O174,
        name: James,
        gender: Male,
        fruits: [
            id: 2,
            fruit_id: B456,
            name: Orange,
            Quantity: 34,
        ]        
    }
]
```

Comment: is a single user have multiple fruits?

Comment: @Garry yes a user has many fruits

Answer (score 0):

You should create a relationship inside Model\User. Then, you can use [with()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) or [load()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections#method-load).

Example:

```
Users::all()->load('fruits');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: the data in the fruits did not display, it is only showing **fruits: []**  not data fetched.

    **fruit - model**
    `public function users() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Users::class, 'fruit_id');
    }`

    **users - model**
    `public function fruits()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Fruits::class, 'fruit_id');
    }`

    `public function index()
    {
        return Users::all()->load('fruits');
    }`

Comment: why does your fruit_id, from the users table, contain "B456"? It should contain ID from fruits (1, 2, 3, .. etc)

Comment: That is the fruit id, what do you mean it should contain (1, 2, 3 .. I don't understand can you explain better or rather **edit** my code above to explain

Comment: also the fruit_id is randomly generated with rand() when inputting the fruit.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make one-to-many relationship between tables

table->users

**Id** - Name - Gender

table->fruits

Id - **user_id** - Name - Quantity

```
class User extends Model{
    public function fruits(){
        return $this->hasMany(Fruit::class,'user_id');
    }
}

class Fruit extends Model{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id');
    }
}

User::with('fruits')->get();
```